# finding the derivative of w'Bw with respect to w

Tags: linear-algebra

How should I approach to proving the following?

$d(w^TBw)/dw = 2Bw$ where $B$ is a symmetrical matrix and $w$ is a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the thing as 
$$
S = \sum_i \sum_j w_i b_{ij} w_j
$$
Differentiate with respect to $w_k$, remembering that $\frac{dw_i}{dw_k}$ is $1$ for $i = k$ and $0$ otherwise, to get
$$
A = \frac{dS}{dw_k} = \sum_i\sum_j \frac{dw_i}{dw_k} b_{ij} w_j + \sum_i\sum_j w_i b_{ij}\frac{dw_j}{dw_k}
$$
by the product rule. Then simplify using that "remember that" clause:
\begin{align}
A &= \sum_i\sum_j \frac{dw_i}{dw_k} b_{ij} w_j + \sum_i\sum_j w_i b_{ij} \frac{dw_j}{dw_k}\\
&= \sum_j b_{kj} w_j + \sum_i w_i b_{ik}\\
&= \sum_j b_{kj} w_j + \sum_i w_i b_{ki}\\
&= \sum_j b_{kj} w_j + \sum_j w_j b_{kj}\\
&= 2\sum_j b_{kj} w_j
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
(w+h)^T B(w+h) &= W^TBw +  h^TBw +  W^TBh +  h^TBh\\
&= W^TBw +  2\langle h , Bw \rangle +  h^TBh \\
h^TBh &= o(h)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{d(w^\top Bw)}{dw} & = \sum_i \frac{d(w^\top Bw)}{w_i}e_i\\
\frac{d(w^\top Bw)}{w_i} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(w+he_i)^\top B(w+he_i)-w^\top Bw}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{w^\top Bw+h^2e_i^\top Be_i-2he_i^\top Bw-w^\top Bw}{h} \\
&= 2e_i^\top Bw\\
\frac{d(w^\top Bw)}{dw} & = \sum_i 2e_i^\top Bwe_i\\
&=2Bw
\end{align}